# ruby encode a p12 certificate(binary) and send as a json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ssl, openssl

I have a pem certificate with a private key.
I am using the above information to generate a p12 certificate which is password protected as follows:

```
  def p12_cert
    ca_cert = x509_cert(File.open("#{root}/ca-cert.crt").read)
    p12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.create(@random_pass, 'My Certificate',
          rsa_pkey(private_key), x509_cert(public_cert), [ca_cert])
    create_file('p12', p12.to_der, ':ASCII-8BIT')
  end
```

The issue is this is in binary format and cannot be transmitted via a json API.

Can someone how me how to encode it(maybe base64) so that this can be sent as a JSON response?

EDIT: I opened the p12 file for read and then tried to base64 encode, got the following:

> irb(main):017:0> enc_p12 = Base64.encode64(p12) TypeError: no implicit
>   conversion of OpenSSL::PKCS12 into String

Comment: Does the code at https://github.com/Mitka20/tango_api/blob/2cc0127b8fc601526ddd000ff1ac46d6531592c0/tango_api.rb help?

Comment: @sheppe. I am not sure. In your example you read the p12 file, but I am not sure how to send it via JSON(non-binary format)

Comment: The key is attached to the request in the line: https.key = p12.key
Also, that's not my code but it seems relevant. :)

Comment: not sure if that gives me what I need. I want the  whole p12 file/data encoded to be sent via json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't usually encode the PKCS12 object itself but the raw file. Something like
`Base64.encode64( File.read(filename, mode: 'rb')`